# Why is the D3 chart not appearing in my LeafletJS popups?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

Can someone tell me why my d3 chart is not appearing in my popups? Full [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/doss1/7ozt4Lnu/) .

The dataset shown for my popups is hypothetical for now, just trying to test and make sure I can get the basics working.

> here's my code:

```
var onEachFeature = function onEachFeature(feature,layer){

var div = $('<div id="chart"><h3>Ethnic Group Distribution</h3><svg/></div>')[0];
var popup = L.popup().setContent(div);

layer.bindPopup(popup);

//Width and height
        var w = 400;
        var h = 300;
        var barPadding = 1;

        var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                        11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("chart")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d * 4);
           })
           .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d * 4;
           });
};

L.geoJson(afghanDistricts, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to compile the popup's content string to DOM, `L.Popup`'s `setContent` method already does that for you:

```
setContent( <String|HTMLElement> htmlContent )
```

> Sets the HTML content of the popup.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-setcontent

You can't initialize the chart when the popup isn't open. The content `div` element will only be attached to the DOM when the popup is open. It gets removed again the popup closes. So you'll need to initialize the chart everytime the popup opens. You can do that by using the `popupopen` event of your map instance:

```
L.mapbox.map(...).on('popupopen', function () {
    // Do stuff 
});
```

> Fired when a popup is opened (using openPopup method).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-popupopen

When using D3's `select` method to fetch an element by unique identifier, you'll need to prefix a `#` character:

```
D3.selector('#chart')
```

> For example, you can select by tag ("div"), class (".awesome"), unique identifier ("#foo"), attribute ("[color=red]"), or containment ("parent child").

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Also you don't need to add an `svg` element in the content since you're already appending a new `svg` element: `.append("svg")`. That creates a new `svg` element and appends it.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var afghanDistricts = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"stroke":"#555555","stroke-width":2,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#555555","fill-opacity":0.5,"Pashtun":0.43,"Tajik":0.12,"Uzbek":0.05,"Turkmen":"0.00","Hazara":"0.00","District":"Argo","Province":"Kandahar"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.69921875,32.08257455954592],[61.69921875,32.879587173066305],[62.666015625,32.879587173066305],[62.666015625,32.08257455954592],[61.69921875,32.08257455954592]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":0.32,"Tajik":"0.20","Uzbek":0.01,"Turkmen":0.02,"Hazara":"0.00","District":"Jurm","Province":"Farah"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[62.75390625,32.95336814579932],[62.75390625,33.76088200086917],[63.69873046874999,33.76088200086917],[63.69873046874999,32.95336814579932],[62.75390625,32.95336814579932]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":0.05,"Tajik":"0.50","Uzbek":0.21,"Turkmen":"0.00","Hazara":"0.00","District":"Ragh","Province":"Ghor"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[63.74267578125,33.54139466898275],[63.74267578125,34.43409789359469],[65.14892578125,34.43409789359469],[65.14892578125,33.54139466898275],[63.74267578125,33.54139466898275]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":"0.00","Tajik":0.01,"Uzbek":"0.10","Turkmen":"0.20","Hazara":"0.40","District":"Highan","Province":"Kabul"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[64.53369140625,35.15584570226544],[64.53369140625,35.94243575255426],[65.56640625,35.94243575255426],[65.56640625,35.15584570226544],[64.53369140625,35.15584570226544]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":"0.00","Tajik":0.01,"Uzbek":"0.20","Turkmen":"0.30","Hazara":0.04,"District":"Nusay","Province":"Kunduz"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[65.58837890625,33.30298618122413],[65.58837890625,34.32529192442733],[66.90673828125,34.32529192442733],[66.90673828125,33.30298618122413],[65.58837890625,33.30298618122413]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":"0.20","Tajik":"0.00","Uzbek":"0.00","Turkmen":"0.10","Hazara":"0.20","District":"Zebak","Province":"Logar"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[65.98388671875,34.72355492704219],[65.98388671875,35.53222622770337],[66.95068359374999,35.53222622770337],[66.95068359374999,34.72355492704219],[65.98388671875,34.72355492704219]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Pashtun":"0.10","Tajik":"0.10","Uzbek":0.28,"Turkmen":"0.10","Hazara":"0.00","District":"Wakhan","Province":"Nimruz"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[67.32421875,34.43409789359469],[67.32421875,35.42486791930558],[68.37890625,35.42486791930558],[68.37890625,34.43409789359469],[67.32421875,34.43409789359469]]]}}]}

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG9zcyIsImEiOiI1NFItUWs4In0.-9qpbOfE3jC68WDUQA1Akg';

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', null, {
  'center': [0, 0],
  'zoom': 0
}).on('popupopen', function () {

  var w = 400;
  var h = 300;
  var barPadding = 1;
  var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
   .append("svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - (d * 4);
    })
    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d * 4;
    });

});

var geojson = new L.GeoJSON(afghanDistricts, {
 onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(new L.popup().setContent('<div id="chart"><h3>Ethnic Group Distribution</h3></div>'));
 }
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(geojson.getBounds());
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mapbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapbox"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason in my real world test, I am getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: L.GeoJson is not a function". I'll keep troubleshooting.

Comment: You can initialize a Leaflet GeoJSON layer in two ways, the default way is doing: `var layer = new L.GeoJSON()` the factory way is doing: `var layer = L.geoJson()`. What you are doing: `L.GeoJson` won't work. The actual class is called `L.GeoJSON` which can be called with the `new` keyword, the factory method is called `L.geoJson` and can be called without the `new` keyword.

Comment: I was doing 'new L.GeoJson' and was getting the error. But, I was able to use the alternative and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
    var svg = d3.select("chart")//not work because chart is not bound to the DOM
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
```

do this:

```
        var svg = d3.select(div)//the div which holds the tooltip
                    .append("svg")
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xj5un1t9/)